# Convert comma separated list of integers into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

I'm trying to initialize an int array with a string that contains list of comma separated numbers.

I tried to directly assign string to array,

```
string sizes = "2,10,65,10"; 
int[] cols = new int[] { sizes };
```

but it obviously fails:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

How to convert string into sequence of integers?

Comment: 1. `.Split()` 2. cast 3. Have a beer. (in this particular order)

Comment: "I want something easy and not complicated. If it's possible in one line" --- learning is an iterative process. First learn how to implement it in any way - even bloated and 30 lines, but get it worked. Otherwise you'll copy-paste for all your "career"

Comment: something like IEnumerable<string> s = sizes.split(); IEnumerable<int> rsults = s.foreach(t=>Convert.ToInt32(t)); Then put results in the array.

Comment: You could write an entire program in "one line".   But it would be crap.   You want something simple and easy to understand.  The number of lines is irrelevant.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for you answer. I agree with you seriously! But at this moment I have a serious block!! Some problems are not letting me to think so much and I need to continue to work so quick for a delay. I'm working under pressure....I hope that my question was not so demanding.

Comment: "But at this moment I have a serious block" --- if such a trivial task blocks you.... uhm, when you have a time - try to learn c# instead of doing real job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want one line? Use LINQ:

```
int[] cols = sizes.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file to make it work.

Without LINQ you'd need a loop:

```
var source = sizes.Split(',');
var cols = new int[source.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
{
    cols[i] = int.Parse(source[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1. Agree that `Select(x => int.Parse(x))` is simple version, complex one would be `.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray()`  :)

Comment: Would this throw an exception if one of the items was not an Int? Like "2,6,ABC,25"?