# Is there a way to populate a stack or array using the input from an HTML textarea?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

On my webpage, I have a textarea running at the server, prompting users to add serial numbers. I wan to use the user input to populate an array, a vector, or a stack (in general, a container) in my c# codefile.

I have my text area with attributes: id="serialno_textbox" and runat="server". In my codefile, I currently have a string called serialno = serialno_textbox.Value. I have called a stack called serial_numbers but not initialized them.

```html
<textarea id="serialno_textbox" rows="10" cols="50" runat="server">Enter Serial Numbers separated by spaces</textarea>
```

```cs
string serialno = serialno_textbox.Value;
Stack<string> serial_numbers;
```

if the user inputs something such as

```
serialnumber1 serialnumber2 serialnumber3
```

which is essentially just strings of numbers and letters separated by spaces,
then I which the outcome to be that the stack's contents are

```
Stack<string> serial_numbers = {serialnumber1 serialnumber2 serialnumber3}
```

Comment: [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) the value on `' '`. The result will be a `string[]`, which you can then use to create the `Stack`:  `var serial_numbers = new Stack(stringArray)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert comma separated list of integers into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761210/convert-comma-separated-list-of-integers-into-an-array). Just substitute "space" for "comma". Or [Best way to specify whitespace in a String.Split operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6111298/215552) for less thinking :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the HTML aspect isn't really important. If you want to take a string of space-separated strings, you can use [`string#Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) and split on the space character (`' '`); like so:

```
var split = "first second third".Split(' ');
// ["first", "second", "third"]
```

Now that you have an array (an `IEnumerable`), you can simply pass it into the `Stack` constructor: like so:

```
var stack = new Stack<string>(split);
```